# How Insert an image on all pages of a word (With VBA macros)?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I try to insert an image every word page.

I know that the command is Next in a for loop, but it is difficult for me to program it with that loop.

This is my code:

```
Sub InsertImage()
Dim oILS As InlineShape, oShp As Shape
Set oILS = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
 "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png", LinkToFile:=False, _
 SaveWithDocument:=True)
Set oShp = oILS.ConvertToShape
With oShp
  .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
  .Left = -55
  .Top = 471.1
  .Height = 21.5
  .Width = 522

  
End With
End Sub
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems to me that the easiest way is to [**insert one image into the header or footer**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/insert-same-picture-in-word-for-multiple-pages/f0c0bff0-cf3b-4fe1-a17b-2a615a291850) - in this case, you do not need to go through all the pages of the document and only one image is inserted, which will be displayed on all sheets. But there [**are other ways**](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7541/is-it-possible-to-insert-image-on-each-page-of-word-document) - for example, Watermark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the way to do it on all pages. If it helps anyone, here it is:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, Shp As Shape, ImageName As String
ImageName = "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png"
With ActiveDocument
Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Set Shp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=ImageName, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=Rng).ConvertToShape
With Shp
.Left = -55
.Top = 471.1
.Width = 522
.Height = 21.5
.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind

End With
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @Toto I thought you understood, sorry, editing it...

Comment: The true answer to this is to put the image in headers or footers, not in the main story. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/HeaderFooterRibbon.htm and https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html. In a well-constructed Word document, pages are very flexible and images placed in a page will move as text is added or subtracted.